# Set default settings for all new multisites?

Tags: multisite

Where do I set the site settings which should be on all sites in the multisite network, and used when a new one is created.
For example I wish to Disable "Show Avatars" under Discussion, and I want this the default setting for everyone, and also every new site.

How do I do this?

Comment: These might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250507/set-multisite-settings-when-new-site-created?rq=1 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177819/customize-default-settings-on-new-sites-on-multisite?rq=1